# обновление значения Label на SplitPane

Tags: java, javafx, update, label

Есть некое JavaFx приложение со SplitPane на сцене.
На SplitPane есть 2 Label'а.
Как в цикле обновить значения Label'ов на форме с задержкой в 1 сек?
Нашел вот такое решение

```
public void start(Stage myStage) {


    myStage.setTitle("JavaFXSkeleton.");
    SplitPane sp = new SplitPane();
    sp.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    Label labelUp = new Label("test");
    Label labelDw = new Label("тест");

    Scene scene = new Scene(sp,800,800);
    myStage.setScene(scene);

    final StackPane sp1 = new StackPane();
    sp1.getChildren().add(labelUp);
    final StackPane sp2 = new StackPane();
    sp2.getChildren().add(labelDw);

    sp.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : dictionary.entrySet())
                {
                    String key = pair.getKey();                      //ключ
                    String value = pair.getValue();                  //значение
                    updateMessage(pair.getKey());
                    System.out.println(key + ":" + value);
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                }
                return null ;
            }
        };
        task.messageProperty().addListener((obs, oldMessage, newMessage) -> labelDw.setText(newMessage));
        task.messageProperty().addListener((obs, oldMessage, newMessage) -> labelUp.setText(newMessage));
        new Thread(task).start();
    });

    sp.getItems().addAll(sp1, sp2);
    sp.setDividerPositions(0.5f, 0.5f);


    // показать подмостки и сцену на них
    myStage.show();
}
```

Проблема этого решения в том, что оно обновляет значения в обоих Label одинаково. Как сделать обновление значений 2хLabel в одном треде?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать проперти *title* (*titleProperty()*) и метод *updateTitle*, аналогично *updateMessage*, или расширить класс *Task*, добавив свою проперти по примеру реализации message.
Также можно по-месту в методе *call* обновить значения меток, обернув labelDw.setText(...)в Platform.runLater(), но такое решение, конечно, "плохо пахнет".